# Why does RedirectToRoutePermanent add "count=0" to querystring?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, routes, redirect

I'm using ASP.NET 4.0 Routing and am reading route info from database and adding the routes as below. In a nutshell, my custom object "RouteLookup" contains the route information including the ID of another RouteLookup that it may or may not be redirected to. Here's an example of two RouteLookup entries in the db:

```
    RouteLookupID   RouteName       RelativePath    RequestHandler  RouteHandler    IsSecure    RedirectedToRoute
    13              PrivacyRoute    about/privacy   privacy.aspx    NULL               0             0
    14              PrivacyRoute1   privacy         privacy.aspx    NULL               0             13
```

RouteLookupID 14 is a legacy route that needs to be permanently redirected to RouteLookupID 13. The problem I'm running up against is when I request "http://mydomain.com/privacy" from the browser and watch Fiddler results, it actually redirects TWICE and adds a "count=0" as a querystring parameter! I have NO IDEA where this parameter is coming from as I have no process, httphandler, etc that is adding that explicitly.

What the heck is happening here? Any ideas are greatly appreciated and the rest of the relevant code is below.

I have a class, BaseRoute, which inherits from Route, so I can pass my custom RouteLookup object along with it to be examined in the custom RouteHandler which I've named BaseRouteHandler.

```
Public Class PageRouter

Private Shared db As New QADBDataContext

''''''' Is called from Global Application_Start
Public Shared Sub MapRoutes(routeColl As RouteCollection)

    Dim routeLookups As IEnumerable(Of RouteLookup) = From rt In db.RouteLookups Select rt

    For Each rtLookUp As RouteLookup In routeLookups
        Dim parameterizedURL As String = BuildParameterizedVirtualPath(rtLookUp)

            ' Determine handler and route values
            If rtLookUp.RouteHandler Is Nothing Then
                RouteTable.Routes.Add(rtLookUp.RouteName, New BaseRoute(parameterizedURL, New BaseRouteHandler(), rtLookUp))
            Else
                RouteTable.Routes.Add(rtLookUp.RouteName, New BaseRoute(parameterizedURL, Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("QA." + rtLookUp.RouteHandler)), rtLookUp))
            End If            
    Next
End Sub

Protected Shared Function BuildParameterizedVirtualPath(rtLookUp As RouteLookup) As String

    Dim parameterizedURL As String = rtLookUp.RelativePath
    For Each param As RouteParameter In rtLookUp.RouteParameters
        parameterizedURL &= "/{" + param.Name + "}"
    Next
    Return parameterizedURL

End Function

Public Shared Sub RedirectToRoutePermanent(rtData As RouteData)

    Dim route As BaseRoute = DirectCast(rtData.Route, BaseRoute)
    Dim rtLookup As RouteLookup = route.RouteLookup
    Dim newRtLookupID As Integer = rtLookup.RedirectedToRoute
    Dim newRtLookup As RouteLookup = (From rt In db.RouteLookups Where rt.RouteLookupID = newRtLookupID).SingleOrDefault
    HttpContext.Current.Response.RedirectToRoutePermanent(newRtLookup.RouteName, rtData.Values.Values)

End Sub
End Class
```

Custom Route class:

```
Public Class BaseRoute
Inherits Route

Private _routeLookup As RouteLookup = Nothing

Public Sub New(url As String, routeHandler As IRouteHandler, routeLookup As RouteLookup)
    MyBase.New(url, routeHandler)
    _routeLookup = routeLookup

End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property RouteLookup As RouteLookup
    Get
        Return _routeLookup
    End Get
End Property
End Class
```

Custom RouteHandler:

```
Public Class BaseRouteHandler
Implements IRouteHandler

Protected _baseRoute As BaseRoute = Nothing
Protected _rtLookup As RouteLookup = Nothing

Protected Overridable Sub InitializeContext(ByVal requestContext As System.Web.Routing.RequestContext)

    _baseRoute = DirectCast(requestContext.RouteData.Route, BaseRoute)
    _rtLookup = _baseRoute.RouteLookup

End Sub


Public Function GetHttpHandler(ByVal requestContext As System.Web.Routing.RequestContext) _
                        As System.Web.IHttpHandler Implements System.Web.Routing.IRouteHandler.GetHttpHandler

    InitializeContext(requestContext)
    EnforceURLStandard(requestContext)
    PerformRedirectIfNeeded(requestContext)
    Return GetPageHandler(requestContext)

End Function


Protected Overridable Sub PerformRedirectIfNeeded(ByVal requestContext As System.Web.Routing.RequestContext)

    If _rtLookup.RedirectedToRoute > 0 Then
        PageRouter.RedirectToRoutePermanent(requestContext.RouteData)
    End If

End Sub


Protected Sub EnforceURLStandard(ByVal requestContext As System.Web.Routing.RequestContext)

    ' Test for:
    '   * Proper protocol
    '   * www. exists
    '   * must be all lowercase

    Dim scheme As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetComponents(UriComponents.Scheme, UriFormat.UriEscaped)
    Dim rightSide As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetComponents(UriComponents.HostAndPort Or UriComponents.PathAndQuery, UriFormat.UriEscaped)
    Dim newURL As String = Nothing

    If Not rightSide.ToLower().StartsWith("www.") AndAlso Not rightSide.ToLower().StartsWith("localhost") _
        AndAlso Not rightSide.ToLower().StartsWith("uat") AndAlso Not rightSide.ToLower().StartsWith("ux") Then
        newURL = scheme & "://www." & rightSide
    End If

    If _rtLookup.IsSecure <> requestContext.HttpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection Then
        Dim newScheme As String = If(_rtLookup.IsSecure, "https", "http")
        newURL = newScheme & rightSide
    End If

    Dim pattern As String = "[A-Z]"
    If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newURL) Then
        If Regex.IsMatch(newURL, pattern) Then
            newURL = newURL.ToLower()
        End If
    Else
        If Regex.IsMatch(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString(), pattern) Then
            newURL = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower()
        End If
    End If

    If Not newURL Is Nothing Then
        HttpContext.Current.Response.RedirectPermanent(newURL, True)
    End If

End Sub

Protected Overridable Function GetPageHandler(ByVal requestContext As System.Web.Routing.RequestContext) As System.Web.IHttpHandler

    Return TryCast(BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath("/" & _rtLookup.RequestHandler, GetType(Page)), Page)

End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, figured out what was happening here. RedirectToRoutePermanent doesn't terminate the request like RedirectPermanent(url, true) does. I rewrote the PageRouter.RedirectToRoutePermanent as such, which resolved the issue:

```
 Public Shared Sub RedirectToRoutePermanent(rtData As RouteData)

    Dim route As BaseRoute = DirectCast(rtData.Route, BaseRoute)
    Dim rtLookup As RouteLookup = route.RouteLookup
    Dim newRtLookupID As Integer = rtLookup.RedirectedToRoute
    Dim newRtLookup As RouteLookup = (From rt In db.RouteLookups Where rt.RouteLookupID = newRtLookupID).SingleOrDefault

    Dim hostAndPort As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetComponents(UriComponents.HostAndPort, UriFormat.UriEscaped)
    Dim newURL As String = Nothing

    Dim scheme As String = If(rtLookup.IsSecure, "https", "http")
    newURL = scheme & "://" & hostAndPort
    newURL &= "/" & newRtLookup.RelativePath

    If rtData.Values.Count > 1 Then
        For i As Integer = 1 To rtData.Values.Count - 1
            newURL &= "/" & rtData.Values(i)
        Next
    End If

    HttpContext.Current.Response.RedirectPermanent(newURL, True)

End Sub
```